# What purpose does the cop play in Hotel Artemis?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, hotel-artemis

In *Hotel Artemis* Jodie Foster's character goes against the rules to rescue a cop. We find out that she knew her son when they were younger. After being patched up she is released and never seen again.

Exactly what purpose did she play in the overall plot? The plot would have been the same had she not been there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same thought the first time I saw the movie; however, if it wasn't for the appearance of the cop, Morgan, Jean would have kept avoiding the tragic story of Beau, her son. Her emotional fallout from his apparent drug overdose is what initially led to her alcoholism and losing her medical license.

Jean being forced to think about her son's death is how she eventually gets the courage to interrogate the Wolf King and find out the truth about what happened to her son when he mentions her son, "Beau". Then, to bring the story full circle, we discover that the Wolf King's remorse for the killing and the impact on Jean is what prompted him to create the Hotel Artemis.

Comment: Nicely put (+1 when the day is over)! ;-) In addition to that it's also another domino piece that breaks her nice little controlled paradise and shows her that maybe sometimes you *have* to break the rules.